# NHibernate timeout with SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate

I have an ASP.Net application with backend in C# that is using NHibernate with SQL Server.

Recently I have noticed that during a long time doing some tasks in a certain page of the web, it freezes and a timeout comes in (NHibernate exception).

After the timeout problem I go to SQL Server Management Studio and I can see in the monitor how there are like dozens of processes without any state and all to the same database:

[image: Processes in SQL Server monitor]

I have searched for solutions everywhere, and I don't know if I'm probably disposing the session incorrectly. Here is how I dispose the session:

```
public static void DisposeSession()
{
    FlushSession(true); // Method that does a commit if there is a transaction
    ISession Session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);

    if (Session != null)
    {
        Session.Close();
        Session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I'm currently using WebForms and there are no shared sessions between requests, sessions are being disposed correctly.

The problem is when I start going though different parts of my web (so doing new requests), the processes start growing like in the image... and at a certain point, the webpage responds with a runtime error or timeout.

How can I control this behaviour?
It's possible only to have one process per request and when disposing, closing the process?

**Edit 2:**

I was wrong, the session management is done right with the method provided in the first answer. There are processes but they are correctly managed by NHibernate.

Comment: Whatever the rest of the code does, the very fact that you have a *static* `DisposeSession` that *gets* a session from somewhere just to *unsafely* dispose it means your data access code has serious issues. A *session* is the same as a connection - you use it for the shortest time possible, in a `using()` block so it gets disposed and closed no matter what. You *don't* share it. If an exception occurs, the session is useless anyway and has to be discarded. What you share is the *factory*.

Comment: In other words, it's not possible to help with this information. Your code is leaking connections, it's guaranteed to leak sessions in case of exceptions, it's *guaranteed* to block if multiple requests try to use the same session. The problem isn't `DisposeSession` though. You shouldn't even have such a method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right... It's possible to create and save the session in "Application_BeginRequest" method and Disposing it in "Application_EndRequest" without a static method and without usings... is it possible and safe?

Comment: No. It's the same bug. You still have a global session - why don't you just use it directly in your code? Is there *any* reason you want to reuse the session? Just pass the session as a parameter if you need it in multiple places, instead of trying to find it in some global/magic location. This will also make your code a *lot* easier to test.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok thank you very much for your answer... I'll try to follow your steps

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you do not know what does `CurrentSessionContext`. To me, it looks very likely it does retrieve the session from something like the `HttpContext`, which is a common practice in web applications and allows handling them with a short live (http requests are supposed to be short), without sharing among requests, and without leaking if correctly handling end of request.

Comment: @Frédéric it's a common bug, not a common practice. It's exactly the same as database connections, with the caveat that sessions are even more fragile - they aren't thread safe. A single exception and you have to discard it. Doing so with an HttpContext variable is *hard*. Besides - **why** store this in HttpContext when a field in the form or controller would work just as well?

Comment: @Frédéric the only thing worse is to open a transaction on BeginRequest. This will open a database connection immediatelly and keep it open until the request ends, accumulating database locks

Comment: This is not that hard at all. Not harder than correctly disposing a session hold by a controller or a webform. Personally with MVC I favor using an `ActionFilter` for handling this, which gives more control than globally handling it in the controller. An http request is usually a good match for an unit of work, so that makes really sense to bound to it the session. If http requests are that long that it causes deadlock troubles, there is maybe something wrong with what business they do. But many other patterns are valid too, provided they keep the session short lived and not shared.

Comment: About opening the connection earlier: yes, but not much an issue. Locks are not issued until a query happen, and are not issued on reads unless using something like the SQL Server legacy read committed mode which was issuing shared locks. (Fortunately SQL Server now supports its "read committed snapshot" mode which works a bit like Oracle read committed do since years, without locks.) As for transactions with stronger isolation modes, of course they should not span something like an ORM UoW which usually involves way to much objects for such transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure your `CurrentSessionContext` does not share session among requests.

Typically this kind of context stores session in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` dictionary. This is a safe place for ensuring it will not end up shared with other http requests.
If instead it shares session between requests, your application would fail for most users once under load.
If it uses a `ThreadContext` or a `CallContext`, it will regularly fails for some requests under load, due to "ASP.Net thread agility" causing some http request to switch threads and lose their previous `ThreadContext` and `CallContext`. `HttpContext.Current.Items` is guaranteed to be preserved when a http request switches threads, not those other ones.

If this `CurrentSessionContext` looks right, then fix your `DisposeSession`. It does not ensure your session will be closed in case of a failed flush.

It should probably be more like:

```
public static void DisposeSession()
{
    try    
    {    
        FlushSession(true); // Method that does a commit if there is a transaction
    }
    finally
    {
        ISession Session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);

        if (Session != null)
        {
            // Dispose closes the session too. And Close dispose the transaction
            // if there was one. And transaction Dispose rollbacks if it was pending.
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, check this `DisposeSession` is always called whatever the way your request ends. Especially check what happens on requests triggering an exception. This include some redirect cases which work with a `ThreadAbortException`, like `Response.Redirect("...")`.

**Session management:**

About the session management pattern I usually use, I bound it to dependency injection, with a per request life cycle and an http module ensuring it gets disposed whatever the outcome of the request, with transaction handled by an action filter (MVC).

Your pattern is far from that. If you wish to change it, you may have it easier following this [blog post series](https://ayende.com/blog/4805/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-limiting-session-scope) from an old timer contributor to NHibernate and author of NHibernate profiler.

Comment: What you write holds for Entity Framework but *not* NHibernate. Unlike EF contexts, a session is a hot potato that has to be carefully handled. Exception and thread safety are the main problem - a single database error and you have to create a *new* session. The old one is useless. This means that you can't inject the session, you have to inject the factory.

Comment: Whether I deal with EF or NH, on a session or context failure, I always discard it (dispose). And just leave it in that state, because I let the exception flows and my error pages do not need a session. When I am in a particular case requiring some db interaction after the failure and inside the same request, the class having that need holds a dependency on the session factory and gets a fresh session used only for that particular need and immediately disposed afterward. (BtW, I will very likely never trust a failed EF context either.)

Comment: EF contexts don't fail. They *are* exception safe. If you want to recover eg from a deadlock, you can. With NH though, if you don't have access to the *factory* you have to restart the request. The *factory* is the equivalent of DbContext, not the session

Comment: Anyway, I suspect the OP sees pooled connections that were created due to the delayed disposal of sessions and there is no actual problem caused *by the connections*. Without even an exception stack trace, I'd guess something else is going on. Perhaps a global transaction?

Comment: Maybe. Getting rid of stale connections would anyway help rule that out and find the actual cause. Or time to ask a DBA to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for all your support!! I was wrong and this correct was right! So the bounty is for you.

Comment: Thanks, I had not even see there was a bounty!